# IIS Dynamic Compression Failing

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, compression

I'm trying to get Dynamic Compression on IIS 8.5 to work (particularly with JSON). I'm using Windows Server 2012, IIS 8.5 and a very simple ASP.NET MVC site returning an ActionResult in the form of JSON. Firstly I have done all the usual steps, enabling Dynamic Compression in IIS at the server and site level, edited my applicationHost.config with the correct MIME types, frequency etc.

I have enabled FailedRequestTrace logging, and what is strange is that my request is reporting a successful compression, however Chrome/Fiddlr disagree:

[image]

And the response in Trace logging contains the header "Content-Encoding: gzip":

[image]

But the response in Chrome/IE/Fiddlr does not contain that header nor is the response compressed, it would appear that something else is interfering! Please help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the server is serving the response zipped (use WireShark to determine this) but you are seeing the response deflated in the browser it's likely to be your antivirus unzipping before the content gets to your browser

[WireShark](https://www.wireshark.org/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I've tested it with Wireshark and the response is compressed when it reaches my machine. The culprit was indeed Anti-virus (specifically ESET Endpoint), HTTP scanning was enabled which was uncompressing the response. Since disabling this option all works fine! :)

Comment: After several hours of trying to find out why gzip compression wasn't working this post saved me. Thanks so much Matthew

Comment: I do confirm it was my case (Eset endpoint antivirus). Disabling protection didn't help - gzip appeared only after I uninstalled it. Will check what exact setting influences it. Thanks!