# IIS dynamic compression 'ALREADY_CONTENT_ENCODING'

Tags: c#, .net, http, iis

Hey I'm trying to find out why gzip is not working on IIS and I ran the failed request tracing - I see this for some of the JS files in the trace

```
DYNAMIC_COMPRESSION_START
DYNAMIC_COMPRESSION_NOT_SUCCESS Reason="ALREADY_CONTENT_ENCODING" 
DYNAMIC_COMPRESSION_END
```

I also see this on the most important JS file on the site:

```
DYNAMIC_COMPRESSION_START
GENERAL_SET_RESPONSE_HEADER HeaderName="Vary", HeaderValue="Accept-Encoding", Replace="false"
DYNAMIC_COMPRESSION_SUCCESS
DYNAMIC_COMPRESSION_DO OriginalSize="114385", CompressedSize="40328" 
DYNAMIC_COMPRESSION_END
```

But that isn't gzip - its something else. I'm trying to get gzip to work.

The only information I can find regarding this is that there is some content encoding already enabled on the site, so dynamic compression won't execute.

I can't find where to disable this content encoding, how its configured, or anyone else with the same issue.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it *was* getting compressed - but my anti-virus (Bitdefender) was decompressing it before my browser got to take a look

This post here suggests using Wireshark to confirm or deny that this is happening to you: [IIS Dynamic Compression Failing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32950960/iis-dynamic-compression-failing)

However I just remoted into a machine that I know had no anti-virus enabled and checked the Chrome Developer tools through there - sure enough `Content-Encoding: gzip` is present on all my JS and CSS.

Meanwhile on the computer with the anti-virus enabled there is no mention of `Content-Encoding`.

This is because the AV has already decompressed it before the browser gets a chance to.